# On the effective charge of an electron

Tags: homework-and-exercises, semiconductor-physics

Is there such a thing as an effective charge of an electron? There is the concept of effective mass of electron and holes in semiconductors, so does electron charge also vary?

Answer (score 0):

For everyday calculations in electrostatics, this doesn't matter. But when you probe the space very very close to the electron, it does. This is because within that space, virtual electron/antielectron pairs pop in and out of existence, and they alter the apparent magnitude of the charge one would measure the electron to have at those very close distances. This process is called *vacuum polarization* and the resulting "screening effect" becomes increasingly important as the distance between the electron and your measurement device decreases.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue "yes". Any material with a relative permittivity other than 1 effectively reduces the field due to an electron. If you wanted to, you could view this as an electron having a smaller "effective" charge --- altho it's not normally thought of that way.